# Current User Identity not formated correctly in IIS

Tags: asp.net, webforms, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.Net Web Forms project which is using Windows Authentication. When I am running it on my DEV machine (Windows 7) the following line of code properly returns Domain Name and User name separated by a Back Slash ("\") (ie DomainName\UserName):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Ok, when I run my project on my WebServer the above line returns the Domain Name and the User name together but this time without a separator. (ie DomainNameUserName).

I have turned on Windows Authentication on my Web server. I am stumped any ideas?

Comment: It's probably worth providing more detail about the difference between your two environments. Your dev is Win7, but is it running in IIS Express? Casini? IIS? And similarly, what's your webserver environment?

Comment: Thanks, I figure out the problem. I was having an issue with the web server after rebooting it the issue resolved itself.